# Comparing the private member variables of class objects stored in a vector - C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

So I have created a program which can read a .dat file of about 20 lines containing info about different atoms (name, symbol, mass etc) and added them all to a vector of class type I made called Atom.

How would I write a function to find the atom with the highest mass?

Here is my class:

```C++
class Atom
{
    string element, symbol;
    float number;
    float mass;
public:
    Atom(string e, string s, float n, float m){
        element = e; symbol = s; number = n; mass = m;
    }
    string getElement();
    string getSymbol();
    float getNumber();
    float getMass();
    float ratio();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Atom c);
};
```

and the information is added to a vector with the following statements

```
    ifstream fin("atoms.dat");  

    string E, S;
    float M, N;

    vector <Atom> periodic;

    while(!fin.eof()){
        fin >> E >> S >> M >> N;
        Atom Atom(E, S, M, N);
        periodic.push_back(Atom);
    }
```

I want to be able to write a function which finds which atom has the highest mass, I've tried using a max_element function but I keep getting errors. Is there a quick way of comparing the member variables of class objects stored in a vector?

I'm currently using C++ 98 as it is what my course requires.

Thanks

Comment: Here is a nice little blog about it: http://fusharblog.com/3-ways-to-define-comparison-functions-in-cpp/

Comment: The way you tried to use max_element is the key to your question. Why did you leave it out of it?

Comment: `I've tried using a max_element ` Then show us what you wrote so we can explain the correct usage. Else, just take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: Never loop on eof() - see https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof for why.

Comment: "I'm currently using C++ 98 as it is what my course requires." Find another course.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102246/sorting-a-vector-of-objects-in-c)

Comment: It's been 19 years since 1998. It's time to move on...

Comment: @DeiDei: But it's only been just over 5 years since C++98.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you did wrong with `std::max_element`, as you haven't provided what you've tried with it.

```
struct CompareAtomMass
{
    bool operator()(const Atom& lhs, const Atom& rhs) {
        return lhs.getMass() < rhs.getMass();
    }
};
```

and then:

```
vector <Atom> periodic;
Atom max_atom = *max_element(periodic.begin(), periodic.end(), CompareAtomMax());
```

`struct CompareAtomMass` is called a function object. It's a class with `operator()` overloaded to return a `bool`. `std::max_element` requires just such a function object to spit out the max element as it needs a way to compare your `Atom`s.

**EDIT:**
You should mark your getter functions as `const` since they don't change the inner state of the class.

```
string getElement() const;
string getSymbol() const;
float getNumber() const;
float getMass() const;
```

This will allow you to call them from a `const` object of type `Atom` just as the above function object requires (`const Atom&`).

Comment: std::max_element returns an iterator, not a reference

Comment: @RyanP Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: I'm now getting this error: - passing ‘const Atom’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘float Atom::getMass()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         return lhs.getMass() < rhs.getMass();

Comment: You need to make your getter functions const. I will edit the answer in a bit.

Comment: @Daniel Great! Make sure you accept an answer to wrap up the question.

Answer (score 0):

Variation of DeiDeis answer: If you only do this at one place, and don't feel a need to keep a CompareAtomMass function class, you can use a lambda:

```
const auto maxIt = max_element(periodic.begin(), periodic.end(), 
   [](const Atom& lhs, const Atom& rhs) {
    return lhs.getMass() < rhs.getMass();
));
if(maxIt != periodic.end()){
  // use *maxIt ;
}
```

in C++14 and later you can also use `auto` in lambdas:

```
const auto maxIt = max_element(periodic.begin(), periodic.end(), 
   [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
    return lhs.getMass() < rhs.getMass();
));
```

Comment: .. what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to make your member functions `const`.
This will allow this code. Otherwise just remove all `const` from my code.
In case your vector is empty, you will get null pointer.

```
struct AtomMassComparator
{
    bool operator()(const Atom& lhs, const Atom& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.getMass() < rhs.getMass();
    }
};

const Atom* getAtomWithHighestMass(const vector<Atom>& v)
{
    vector<Atom>::const_iterator it = max_element(
        v.begin(), v.end(), AtomMassComparator());
    return v.end() == it ? 0 : &*it;
}
```